# How to access a web service using a proxy in c#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, proxy

I wish to send a HTTP request to a remote web service using the specified proxy. Is this achievable? if so how?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have access to the proxy? How do you normally interact with the proxy?

Comment: @Oded, code like I do not know. I usually interact using my browser.

Comment: question is kinda misleading, are you trying to use a web proxy or a web service?

Comment: I want to connect to a web service, I'd like the origin of the request to be traced to a proxy and not some other ip

Comment: Are use using regular WebRequest or auto-generate client to access the web service?

Comment: JFYI, when answering to not-post owner, like me in your post, use `@` so the person could see your comment in his recent, e.g. `@abatishchev`

Comment: @vondip: Then use my code below

Comment: @abatishchev, great! thank you, going to check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var proxy = new WebProxy("proxy.example.com", 8080)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password") // optional
};

var request = new WebRequest
{
    Proxy = proxy // optional. if null - request goes without proxy, obviously
};

var response = request.GetResponse();
```